# Order of assignment and comparison in an 'if' statement

Tags: c++, c

Looking at the code:

```
int i = 5;
if (i = 0)
{
  printf ("Got here\n");
}
```

What does the C standard have to say about what will get printed? 
Or in more general terms does the assignment happen first or the comparison?

Comment: Which assignment are you worried about. Also note there is no comparison (that is done with ==)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

§6.8.4 says that the syntax for an `if` selection statement is:

```
if ( expression ) statement
```

Further in this section, it mentions that if the expression compares unequal to 0, then *`statement`* is executed. The expression must therefore be evaluated before it can be compared to 0. `i = 0` is an expression which evaluates to 0. For further reference, see §6.5 “Expressions” with regards to §6.5.16 “Assignment operators”, in particular note this excerpt:

> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand. An
>   assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment, but is not an lvalue.

Answer (score 4):

Assignment first, as it is part of the evaluation. The expression of the assignment returns the assigned value, so the expression evaluates as false.

Comment: Any reference to the standard?

Comment: I don't know which part of the standard you want quoted... assignments are expressions, and an `if` must evaluate its expression prior to determining the truth of that expression (by definition).

Answer (score 3):

`i=0` evaluates to 0 thus the output will not happen.

The prior assignment (the first line of source code) is irrelevant to the outcome.

Comment: Yes there is, i is checked for truth. If i is set to zero before the comparison, then we do not print Got here, if the comparison happens first we do.

Comment: @doron - show me which line of code is the comparison, and I will edit accordingly. Thanks

Comment: the C standard says that the expression itself is compared to 0, and that the substatement of an `if` selection statement is only executed if the expression compares unequal to 0. I think @doron wants to know whether the comparison occurs after or before the assignment.

Comment: The value expression `i=0` is compared to `0`.  There definitely is a comparison here.

Comment: @John - thanks, edited accordingly.  Still don't understand the part where 'i is checked for truth'.

Answer (score 2):

The statement `i = 0` will be evaluated and return `0`, so the statement will not be printed.

Answer (score 2):

*When the assignment happens* is irrelevant. What's relevant is the value of `i=0` as an expression, and it's defined to have the value 0.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment happens, which returns a 0, which is false.

Answer (score 0):

The expression of the if clause is evaluated first, the result of which is 0.

This program will never print "Got here\n".

Answer (score 0):

As others already said, the assignment returns the value of that is assigned and so never prints the statement. If you wanted the statement to be printed, you'd have to use `if (i = -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will print. The 0 get assigned to i and then that value is tested for the condition.